# Tabular Sub-report Property

Tags: acumatica

I have a sub-report that retrieves ONLY one field, but it retrieves n values. This means it will be displayed in many rows.
I want to display the sub-report result in a master report in ONLY one row (comma separated or Tabular). Is this applicable?
I tried to make the sub-report Tabular = True, but it displays the results in the master report like 
(1 2 3)
(space 2 space)
(space space 3)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the tabular report must have at least one group.

Try to set a property TabularFreeze to value that cuts off a tabular region.
It is necessary that the red line was directly to the right of your TextBox.
Tabular region will be moved from rows to columns.

Comment: I tried to set a value to TabularFreeze and it displays the result as described. The size of sub-report control is greater than the sub-report size, and it displays the same output.