# Acumatica:How to display one single textbox from rows to columns(in a straight line) in Main report sub line

Tags: report, acumatica

I would like to show the SOShipline.QTY in main lines, and every SOShiplineSplit.QTY under its shipline in straight lines and NOT in rows.

[The report display now and the change I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuSJz.png)

Thanks to anyone who would like to mention [Tabular Sub-report Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551488/tabular-sub-report-property)
Yes, I've tried tabular report, I have met a problem I can not solve for several days. I've posted my problem in another post
[Acumatica:Tabular Report generates unexpected lines when calling as sub report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239823/acumaticatabular-report-generates-unexpected-lines-when-calling-as-sub-report)

For this question only, can somebody point out a way for me to realize my need?

Answer (score 0):

SQL views are not recommended however in this case you might need to create one.  The select statement below will  give you the one line output that you need.  Then you would create a DAC based off the view.  From there you would be able to add the view to your report.

```
-- ------------------------------------------------------------
-- View: usrSOSplit
-- ------------------------------------------------------------

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[usrSOSplit]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsView') = 1)
drop view [dbo].usrSOSplit
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create View [usrSOSplit] as 
SELECT  companyid, shipmentnbr,
        isnull(cast([1] as varchar(50)),'')
        +' '+ isnull(cast([2] as varchar(50)),'')
        +' '+ isnull(cast([3] as varchar(50)),'')
        +' '+ isnull(cast([4] as varchar(50)),'')
        +' '+ isnull(cast([5] as varchar(50)),'')
        +' '+ isnull(cast([6] as varchar(50)),'')
        +' '+ isnull(cast([7] as varchar(50)),'')
        +' '+ isnull(cast([8] as varchar(50)),'')
        +' '+ isnull(cast([9] as varchar(50)),'')
        +' '+ isnull(cast([10] as varchar(50)),'')
        as ListOfQty        
      FROM    
    ( SELECT shipmentnbr,companyid,  splitlinenbr as splitLine , qty FROM    SOShipLineSplit ) p
    PIVOT ( max(qty) FOR [splitline] IN ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10] ) ) AS pvt
```

DAC:

```
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace SoShipSplit
{
  [Serializable]
  public class usrSOSplit : IBqlTable
  {
    #region Shipmentnbr
    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Shipmentnbr")]
    public virtual string Shipmentnbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class shipmentnbr : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region ListOfQty
    [PXDBString(509, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "List Of Qty")]
    public virtual string ListOfQty { get; set; }
    public abstract class listOfQty : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Pal，thank you so much for giving me this. One thing I don't understand is where to/How to add the DAC code.

Comment: Refer the Data Access Classes section, page 259 in the customization guide below.
You'll need to create a customization project and add the DAC.  Once published you should be able to access your SQL view.

https://adn.acumatica.com/content/uploads/2017/08/AcumaticaERP_CustomizationGuide.pdf